# MATLAB : Read line bit in text file and convert into MATRIX

Tags: matlab

MATLAB
I need to read data from o text file like :1111111111111011111111101101010011111111
and convert it into MATRIX form like :

```
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1
```

to convert it into image.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thnx!

Comment: How are those two binary sequences related?

Comment: oh, i just instance it, here :

Comment: 1111111111111000111111111111000011111111111100

Comment: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fscanf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) to read the file into a string, and then convert to numbers (subtracting '0'):

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
x = fscanf(fid,'%s')-'0';
fclose(fid);
```

That will give you a row vector `x`. You may need to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that vector to put into matrix form.

Comment: Thanks a million, it's very useful.